# How can I change the state of clicked button only in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I change the state of clicked button. Now it is changing state of all Accept button to `Save` in the page. I tried to pass the id, but it doesn't work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-chihiro-s4v1cc?file=/src/styles.css

```
const [processRequest, setProcessRequest] = useState("Accept");
    const processRequestData = (e) => {
        const text = "Save";
        setProcessRequest(text,e.target.id);
      };

<section class="col1">

            {
                        searchResults.map(({id, name, mobile}) => (

                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className="playerRow"> 
                                <label key={id}>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="checkStyle1">
                                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="plyName">
                                            <span>{name}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="plyMobile">
                                            <span>{mobile}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="checkStyle2">
                                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                                            <label>Member</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="checkStyle3">
                                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                                            <label>Active Player</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="btnStyle4">
                                            <button type="button" onClick={ () => processRequestData(e)}>{processRequest}</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="btnStyle4">
                                            <input type="button" value="Decline Request"></input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>  
                            
                        </div>
                       
                   ))} 
            </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it for you, you were updating the same string variable for all the array items.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Danile Victor",
    mobile: "3423224232",
    processRequest: "Accept"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Sam Philip",
    mobile: "2312312310",
    processRequest: "Accept"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Von Rodriguz",
    mobile: "5678999010",
    processRequest: "Accept"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Style Dorkin",
    mobile: "7896543212",
    processRequest: "Accept"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Rad",
    mobile: "7009943212",
    processRequest: "Accept"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [acceptPlayer, setAcceptPlayer] = useState("Accept");
  const [requestList, setRequestList] = useState([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [processRequest, setProcessRequest] = useState("Accept");

  useEffect(() => {
    setRequestList(data);
  }, []);
  const processRequestData = (e) => {
    setRequestList(
      requestList.map((r) => {
        if (r.id === e) {
          r.processRequest = "Save";
        }
        return r;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section className="col1">
        {requestList.map(({ id, name, mobile, processRequest }) => (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="playerRow">
              <label key={id}>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="checkStyle1">
                    <input type="checkbox"></input>
                  </div>
                  <div className="plyName">
                    <span>{name}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="plyMobile">
                    <span>{mobile}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="checkStyle2">
                    <input type="checkbox"></input>
                    <label>Member</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="checkStyle3">
                    <input type="checkbox"></input>
                    <label>Active Player</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="btnStyle4">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={(e) => processRequestData(id)}
                    >
                      {processRequest}
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="btnStyle4">
                    <input type="button" value="Decline Request"></input>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried the solution, on click the page become blank and I am getting an error Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, mobile}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.```

Comment: Have you fixed it already?

Comment: Thank you I have fixed that error. One question in that`` map.(r)`` r is the index right ? but where are you returning that ? Didn't understand that part..

Answer (score 0):

`setProcessRequest` takes only single argument. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

You need to track the state of the items clicked, e.g. mapping id of the search result to toggle state.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable `processRequest` for every button. You can make array for each element in `data` so this array (let's say `buttonNames`) would look like this: ["Accept", "Save", "Accept", "something", ...] and inside jsx in .map in onClick you would pass index to `processRequestData` and change value in `buttonNames` by this index. The rendered value of button would be taken from `buttonNames` by index for example `{buttonNames[index]}`.

Comment: Have you got an example to share ?